# Clarification on SKLearn's 'neg_root_mean_squared_error' score

Tags: scikit-learn

If I'm running some RFECV runs with various regressors, using `neg_root_mean_squared_error` as the scoring metric, when I executed the `score = rfe.score(X_train, y_train)` line, I get scores that look like this:

[image: Score_Output]

So, which of these would be a "better" score? I thought `neg_root_mean_squared_error` would produce a negative number? So if these are positive, would I want to aim for the LOWER numbers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RFECV`'s `score` method is still just a delegate to its model's `score` method, and so for these probably the R2 score, not your negative rmse. The negative rmse is being used to determine which number of features to select; you can also see some of those scores in the `grid_scores_` or `cv_results_` attribute, and can use the `mean_squared_error` metric function to find those scores for the refit estimator.